# XML LINQ query returns nothing

Tags: c#, xml, linq, null, xelement

I'm trying to parse an xml file using LINQ, but as I understand the query returns null. (It's WP7)
Here's the code:

```
       var resultQuery = from q in XElement.Parse(result).Elements("Question")
                          select new Question
                          {
                              QuestionId = q.Attribute("id").Value,
                              Type = q.Element("Question").Attribute("type").Value,
                              Subject = q.Element("Subject").Value,
                              Content = q.Element("Content").Value,
                              Date = q.Element("Date").Value,
                              Timestamp = q.Element("Timestamp").Value,
                              Link = q.Element("Link").Value,
                              CategoryId = q.Element("Category").Attribute("id").Value,
                              UserId = q.Element("UserId").Value,
                              UserNick = q.Element("UserNick").Value,
                              UserPhotoURL = q.Element("UserPhotoURL").Value,
                              NumAnswers = q.Element("NumAnswers").Value,
                              NumComments = q.Element("NumComments").Value,
                          };
```

"result" is the xml string, just like this one.
http://i48.tinypic.com/1ex5s.jpg (couldn't post properly formatted text so here's a pic : P )

Error:
http://i48.tinypic.com/2uyk2ok.jpg

Sorry, if I haven't explained it properly and if this has already been asked (tried searching but didn't help).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have run into an XML namespace problem. When you are just querying "Question", the string is translated into an [`XName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xname.aspx) with the default namespace. There are no elements in the default namespace in your XML, only elements in the `urn:yahoo:answers` namespace (see the top level element, where it says `xmlns="urn:yahoo:answers"`).

You need to query the correct XML namespace, like this:

```
var ns = new XNameSpace("urn:yahoo:answers");
var resultQuery = from q in XElement.Parse(result).Elements(ns + "Question");
```

When picking out the individual properties, remember to add the namespace also.

[`XName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xname.aspx) is a class that represents an XML name, which might have a namespace defined by [`XNameSpace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnamespace.aspx). These two classes has an implicit conversion operator implemented that allows you to implicitly convert from `string` to `XName`. This is the reason the calls work by just specifying a `string` name, but only when the elements are in the default namespace.

The implicitness of this makes it <strike>very easy</strike> easier to work with XML namespaces, but when one does not know the mechanism behind, it gets confusing very quickly. The [`XName`class documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xname.aspx) has some excellent examples.

Comment: Thx a lot for your help. Turns out it was all I needed 
`XNamespace ns = doc.Name.Namespace;
var resultQuery = from q in doc.Elements(ns + "Question")`

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to fix it:

1. Add the root element was part since Elements only search one level - XElement.Parse(result).Root.Elements("Question")
2. Use the Descendants method since that will search the entire xml tree.